# Load testing comet based application

Tags: testing

We have developed a comet based application for chat (using streaming approach). The application has been developed in ASP .Net 3.5 sp1. 
The browser has two connections with the server. One for posting and another for receiving chat messages. While load testing with Jmeter or VSTS the posting is getting recorded and load tested but not the receiving portion. Can some one please suggest any load testing tool which can address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the same problem, the top runner for me at the moment is browsermob.com. It has a complete API that allows you to create test scenarios that can "watch and wait" on pages recording every http request made as though they are visiting through a real browser. It gets kind of expensive if you need to test with more than 25 concurrent users (browser users), but seems very reasonably priced from what I have seen so far.

It'd be really interesting to see what tools others who are somewhat technically inept are using.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Stress+Testing+Cometd